# Can I specify a file path using a variable in Rmd?

Tags: image, r-markdown, pandoc, cpu-word

Is there a way to embed images using `![]()` into an R Markdown file by referencing a **variable** for the file path? The following code doesn't work, but was something I tried.

```
---
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
---

# Directory
dirHome = getwd()

# Image directory
dirImg = paste(dirHome, '/screenshots/image.jpeg', sep = "")

![Image from directory](dirImg)
```

I'm creating multiple reports using parameters and would like to access images stored in different folders each time.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Must reference the variable like so:
`` ![Image from directory](`r dirImg`) ``